# Intel 12 gen and Ubuntu 22.10 - abysmal battery life, any solution?

Tags: power-management, battery, performance

I have Lenovo T14 Gen 3 with Intel i7 1260p (no dedicated GPU, only intel one's) and running Ubuntu 22.10
The performance is great (laptop is faster than 2-3 years old desktop with the most powerful i7 at the time) but battery life is a joke.

Youtube playback - 2 hours, general software development - 2-4 hours, internet browsing - 3-4 hours, running some heavy processes (tests, compiling) - 1-1.5 hours.

I also can double boot to windows, I don't develop there but I can see youtube playback - 5 hours. Internet browsing - 5-6 hours.  Which is more than 2 times longer.

Wondering - is there anything can be done to improve that, without loosing a lot of performance.

I've tried TLP - it done nothing with the default settings, I've achieved a bit better battery life by playing with a lot of settings but performance degraded 4 times so it wasn't an option in the end.

I've also tried to disable intel_pstate and used acpi-cpufreq - with no change in behaviour.

I've tried powertop's recommended configurations - results are the same.

I also had Ubuntu 22.04 before installed - situation there wasn't better (i.e. it's not some bug in 22.10)

Can someone advice what else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

It actually kind of was solved by updates. Not sure which exactly, what I've done:

1. Enabled proposed updates for OS, updated kernel. Note I'm also using Ubuntu 22.10 (the latest)
2. Updated firmware, ubuntu didn't show me update option but I've double booted to windows and install firmware from there. Laptop actually bricked and I've had to use "reset pinhole" to do some low level reset and it worked after that.
3. I've added oibafs ppa and updated packages from there.

Not sure what exactly worked, I think it's most likely second item, but if firmaware update didn't work feel free to try the rest.

My results:

- Youtube playback - 2.5 hours
- General software development - 3-5 hours
- Internet browsing - 4-7 hours
- Running some heavy processes (tests, compiling) - 2-2.5 hours

All tests (before and now) were done with ~60% backlight

I'm running youtube in Chrome and it seems it's not optimized for Linux that well yet - when I switch tab so youtube run in a background (so no need to decode the video) battery life improves significantly

It's not good but not abysmal any longer, just bad, but something that you can work with.
Hope they'll improve situation going forward.